# source&dest ports over port forwarding

Tags: networking, ip, tcp

I'm implementing a firewall module, and I have the following system:

1. A "client" with ip 10.1.1.1
2. A firewall
3. A "server with ip 10.1.2.2

The networking in this system is implemented such that the connection between the client and the server is being done through the firewall.
To Allow that, ip forwarding is enabled on the firewall (`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`)

My logic of packet catching and filtering is summarized in a netfilter forward hook. Let's consider only the following part of it:

```c
unsigned int forward_hook_fn (void *priv,
                            struct sk_buff *skb,
                            const struct nf_hook_state *state)
{
/* some variable declarations */
    ip = (struct iphdr*)skb_network_header(skb);
    dip = ntohl(ip->daddr);
    sip = ntohl(ip->saddr);
    protocol = ip->protocol;

    if (protocol == PROT_TCP){
    tcp = (struct tcphdr*)skb_network_header(skb);
    printk("src:%hu dst:%hu, seq:%u\n",ntohs(tcp->source),ntohs(tcp->dest),ntohs(tcp->seq));
}
...
/* irrelevant logic */
...
}
```

My problem:
It looks like I am not getting the correct source and destination port of my packets.

Explanation:
For commands like these:

```bash
ssh -p 555 10.1.1.1 
curl 10.1.1.1
ssh -p 4784 10.1.1
nc 10.1.2.2 1234
.... #and so on.. it doesn't matter what are the specific numbers of course
```

I get the following log:

```
timestamp         src_ip   dst_ip   src_port dst_port protocol action reason count
26/10/22 05:27:52 10.1.2.2 10.1.1.1 37296    582      TCP      drop   254    1
26/10/22 05:30:10 10.1.2.2 10.1.1.1 69       15360    TCP      drop   254    8
26/10/22 05:30:26 10.1.1.1 10.1.2.2 37296    582      TCP      drop   254    1
26/10/22 05:30:43 10.1.1.1 10.1.2.2 69       15360    TCP      drop   254    4
```

Which is weird since I don't see the port I used in the commands + there is not enough types of ports and this make me thinks that something with my port forwarding is not acting the way I would expect (In case my explanation is bad: I would expect to see the ports 555,80(curl?),4784,1234 in the logs)

Thanks

EDIT: I want to clarify that the ports that I see in the log I also see in the `printk` in `dmesg`, so it is not a parsing issue

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't use the transport header for TCP?

Comment: Yep :/ I should have used tcp_hdr, udp_hdr, ip_hdr to convert the skb to the right struct. do you want to submit an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Just write your own answer. I saw what could not be right, but I'm not sure what should have been used instead. Btw, is it worth it rather than using preexisting features like nftables?